# image not rendered when using ngIf

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this basic script:

HTML:

```
<button ion-button (tap)="buttonclick()">Button</button>
<ion-img *ngIf="test" style="width: 20%; vertical-align: middle;" src="../assets/imgs/logo.png"></ion-img>
```

TS:

```
buttonclick()
{
  this.test = true;
}
```

**What I expected to happen:**

clicking the button shows the image.

**What happens:**

clicking the button makes a small grey rectangle appear where the image should be, as if the img source couldn't be found. Leaving the view and returning to it does make the image appear.

What am I doing wrong or how can I fix this issue?
Any help is much appreciated!

**Update:**

After inspection of the source code, I notice a class `img-unloaded`is assigned to the image the first time. When I leave the view and return, the class changes to `img-loaded`, making the image appear. I guess this is an Ionic thing...? How to avoid this behaviour? Using the `img` tag instead of `ion-img` resolves the issue, but I'd rather want to use the `ion-img` tag.

Comment: Does it show if you remove `*ngIf="test"`?

Comment: Replace with "assets/imgs/logo.png."

Comment: Try to use `ngClass` instead of this and add simply toggle display: none / block; should make it work. Or check the img src in devtools, it may point to a wrong path, which causing this behavior

Comment: And also check if the buttonclick is actually triggered (using console.log)

Comment: Removing *ngIf="test" shows the image correctly, so the "../assets/" part is right, I assume. The console tells me the button is triggered. I'll try using ngClass and let you know.

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko I tried toggling it using a `class` named hide but it behaves the same unfortunately (I've updated my question with what I've tried)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `<img>`, as the [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/#img) states:

> Note: ion-img is only meant to be used inside of virtual-scroll

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tdpdth?file=pages/home/home.html) that works

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know ion-img was only for virtual-scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try using img tag.

```
<img *ngIf="test" style="width: 20%; vertical-align: middle;" src="../assets/imgs/logo.png">
```